# C# Interop Delphi DLL

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I Have a third party DLL write in Delphi "a.dll" (without source).

And this DLL has one method with this signature.

```
function GetAny(pFileName: String): String;
```

I can't do a interop call from c# because 'String type' has private access in delphi.

So a build another DLL in delphi to wrapper that call.

## Delphi.

```
function GetAny(pFileName: String): String; external 'a.dll'

function GetWrapper(url : PChar) : PChar; stdcall;
begin
    Result := PChar(GetAny(url)); // I need avoid this String allocation, is throwing a exception.
end;
```

## C#.

```
[DllImport("wrapper.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr GetWrapper(String url);
```

Inside "GetWrapper" i make a call to external "GetAny", the result is OK (in delphi i can debug), but before i get this result back in c# side, it's throwing a Exception.

```
IntPtr test = GetWrapper("a");
String result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(test);
```

Comment: Change your Delphi wrapper to be a procedure that accepts a target buffer of char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wrapper DLL also cannot call GetAny because string is a managed Delphi type that cannot be passed across module boundaries.

The problem is that the return value of GetAny is allocated in one module and deallocated in a different module. It is allocated in the DLL that implements GetAny, and deallocated in the DLL that calls GetAny. Since the two DLLs use different memory managers, you end up trying to deallocate memory that was allocated on a different heap.

If the DLL that implements GetAny can be persuaded to share a memory manager then you could solve that problem readily.

I do question the facts that you present though. As it stands, unless the DLL is designed to be used with ShareMem, that function can never be called safely.

If you were prepared to leak the memory you could try this:

**Delphi**

```
function GetAny(pFileName: string): PChar; external 'a.dll'

procedure GetWrapper(url: PChar; out value: WideString); stdcall;
var
  P: PChar;
begin
    P := GetAny(url);
    if Assigned(P) then
      Value := P
    else
      Value := '';
end;
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("wrapper.dll"]
public static extern void GetWrapper(
    string url,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    out string value
);
```

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the problem is not "String cast", i have made some tests, i belive that GetAny ("a.dll") is raise a Exception.

Comment: What I state is accurate. Unless the DLL is meant for ShareMem, that function cannot be called safely. With the facts in the Q, my answer is accurate.

Comment: Can someone take a look? Two simple projects, thank anyway. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ci2l431tsku52n7/C%23_Delphi%20Interop.rar

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded your code...

The solution could be like this:

- Create a wrapper procedure in Delphi with "cdecl" declaration with 2 parameters of PChar type

  - the first one is IN parameter
  - the second one is OUT parameter

Original Delphi function:

```
function GetAny(pFileName: String): String; external 'a.dll';
```

Delphi – DLL with wrapped function:

```
 procedure GetWrapper (url: PChar; var urlNew: PChar) cdecl;
 var str: string;
 begin
      urlStr = string(url);
      urNewStr := GetAny(urlStr);
      urlNew := PChar(urNewStr);
 end;

 exports
    GetWrapper;
 begin
 end.
```

- In Visual Studio:

Make the project x32 bit (not a x64 as it was in your sample)

- Import DLL as Cdecl

`[DllImport("wrapper.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]`

- Marshaling

`public static extern void GetWrapper ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string url, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out string urlNew);`

- Calling in C#:

  string fileName;// = @"wertwertwertwertwer";

  GetWrapper("2.jpg", out fileName);

  Console.WriteLine(fileName);

In my environment it worked. (Delphi 5 and VS2012).

Hopefully it will work for you also.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It's also totally broken, because you return a pointer to a local variable. And you do also ask the marshaller to call CoTaskMemFree on something that was not allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc.

Comment: Lots of reasons. First of all, the memory that `fnNew` points to is deallocated as soon as the function returns. Secondly, the marshaller things it is meant to deallocate, and calls `CoTaskMemFree` on the returned pointer. Finally, you never called the function the DLL, `GetAny` which was the entire point of the question. As I explained, that's not even possible!

Comment: David, could you please explain why it will not work? Rafael created a wrapper function, that I would recommend to change a little. Instead of function, create a procedure with 2 parameters.

Comment: @David, excuse me for the question repetitions (I just wanted to edit a comment). Thank you for the explanations.
I don’t know how Marshaling allocates and releases the memory.
I’ve edited the function names above for the developers who may be interested and will choose the suitable solution.
(in the previous post I just used the function names that Rafael provided in his DropBox folder)

Comment: 1. It is not right to use Delphi String as parameters in Win32 DLLs.
So, the function function GetAny(pFileName: String): String;  cannot be accessed outside Delphi.   
2. Wrapper with PChar types sounds fine for me.   
3. In this case, the proposed solution is to create a procedure with two PChar parameters: one is IN parameter, another one is OUT parameter.   
4. Call this function from C# code. (It could be that the Marshaling I’ve tried is not a right solution - David is a specialist in this field, maybe he can help with this).